# Resetting Value of <input type="time"> in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, cross-browser

I found an funny cross-browser issue using jQuery's `.val` to clear HTML time inputs. I want to dynamically disable the input and clear the value in a form. It appears that Firefox needs that to happen in a particular order in order to achieve the desired results, Chrome and Safari don't seem to care about this order. I've got the same [code in a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLLe6jqf/26/).

I'm curious if anyone knows what's happening behind the scenes to cause this issue. Is this a bug in jQuery?

```js
$('#reset-jq').click(function() {
    $('#time-jq').val('').prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#reset-jqn').click(function() {
    $('#time-jqn').prop('disabled', true).val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong><code>.val</code> before disable:</strong> works on desktops: Chrome, Safari and Firefox</p>
<input id="time-jq" type="time" value="11:11">
<button id="reset-jq">Clear</button>
<br><br>
<p><strong>disable before <code>.val</code>: </strong> works on desktops: Chrome, Safari, but not Firefox</p>
<input id="time-jqn" type="time" value="11:11">
<button id="reset-jqn">Clear</button>
```

Comment: well first off, mixing jQuery with vanilla JS when manipulating the DOM can cause some discrepancies ... what happens if you swap out the document.getElementById('reset-jqn') with $('reset-jqn').on('click')  ?

Comment: @otherstark, I've updated the jsfiddle and code snippet. No change.

Comment: This is the function implementation for `.val`, right? https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3d732cca6b5076a9d13eee98e2b075b37384cd91/src/attributes/val.js#L16

Comment: Interesting. Seems to be limited to `time` inputs. `text` inputs work with the `.prop('disabled', true).val('')` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, it appears once a `time` input has been `disabled` the `value` attribute can only be changed to a valid `time` value - something like `00:00`, or `13:30`. For example, using:

```
$(#INPUT_ID).prop('disabled', true).val('00:00');
```

will set the input to `disabled`, and change the input to display `12:00 AM` (instead of the default `--:-- --`).

```js
$('#reset-jqn-noval').click(function() {
    $('#time-jqn-noval').prop('disabled', true).val('');
});

$('#reset-jqn').click(function() {
    $('#time-jqn').prop('disabled', true).val('00:00');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>disable before <code>.val</code> with val("")</strong> </p>
<input id="time-jqn-noval" type="time" value="11:11">
<button id="reset-jqn-noval">Clear</button>
<br/><br/>
<p><strong>disable before <code>.val</code> with val("00:00") </strong></p>
<input id="time-jqn" type="time" value="11:11">
<button id="reset-jqn">Clear</button>
```

Turns out the same result happens when using pure JavaScript. Disabling the input before setting the value to `""` has no effect in Firefox. But disabling the input before setting the value to a valid time does work.

```
document.getElementById("INPUT_ID").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("INPUT_ID").value = "";
```

```js
document.getElementById('reset-jqn-noval').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("time-jqn-noval").value = "";
    document.getElementById("time-jqn-noval").disabled = true;  
});

document.getElementById('reset-jqn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("time-jqn").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("time-jqn").value = "";
});

document.getElementById('reset-jqn-value').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("time-jqn-value").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("time-jqn-value").value = "00:00";
});
```

```html
<p><strong>disable after <code>.val</code> with val("")</strong></p>
<input id="time-jqn-noval" type="time" value="11:11">
<button id="reset-jqn-noval">Clear</button>
<br/><br/>
<p><strong>disable before <code>.val</code> with val("")</strong></p>
<input id="time-jqn" type="time" value="11:11">
<button id="reset-jqn">Clear</button>
<br/><br/>
<p><strong>disable before <code>.val</code> with val("00:00") </strong></p>
<input id="time-jqn-value" type="time" value="11:11">
<button id="reset-jqn-value">Clear</button>
```

So, to answer your question, this issue **isn't limited to only jQuery**, as the same result occurs with plain JavaScript. But it's still not known how to clear the disabled time input.

I have filed a [bug for this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1441351).

Comment: Also, when I get the value of the uncleared, disabled input, its value is an empty string and not 11:11, as displayed.